# Does a StructuredProperty reference the parent or child?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Does a StructuredProperty reference the parent or child?

```
class Invoices(ndb.Model): #Child

class Customers(ndb.Model): #Parent
    invoice = ndb.StructuredProperty(Invoices)
```

or...

```
class Customers(ndb.Model): #Parent

class Invoices(ndb.Model): #Child
    customer = ndb.StructuredProperty(Customers)
```

Comment: Both are valid code. Beyond that, your question isn't clear. Which (if either) to use would depend on what you are trying to model.

Comment: Thanks @Greg I wasn't aware that it could go both ways. Just trying to make sense of it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question in the context of "what is the better practice for a NoSQL Datastore",
here's what I can offer.

First, you probably want to name your models in the singular, as they should describe a single
`Invoice` or `Customer` entity, not several.

Next, using a `StructuredProperty` implies that you'd like to keep all of this information in a
single entity - this will reduce write/read ops, but can introduce some limitations. 
(See the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured) -
or this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072491/app-engine-structured-property-vs-reference-property-for-one-to-many-relationsh))

The most common relationship would be a one(`Customer`) to many(`Invoice`) relationship,
which you can structure as below:

```
class Invoice(ndb.Model): #Child
    invoice_id = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)  # 

class Customer(ndb.Model): #Parent
    invoices = ndb.StructuredProperty(Invoices, repeated=True)

    def get_invoice_by_id(self, invoice_id):
        """Returns a customer Invoice by invoice_id. Raises KeyError if invoice is not present."""
        invoice_matches = [iv for iv in self.invoices if iv.invoice_id == invoice_id]
        if not invoice_matches: raise KeyError("Customer has no Invoice with ID %s" % invoice_id)
        return invoice_matches[0]  # this could be changed to return all matches
```

Keep in mind the following restrictions of this implementation:

1. `StructuredProperty`s can not contain repeated properties inside of themselves.
2. The complexity for keeping `invoice_id` globally unique is going to be higher than if `Invoice` were in its own entity-group. (`invoice_key.get()` is always better than the query this requires))
3. You would need an instance method on `Customer` to find an `Invoice` by `invoice_id`.
4. You would need logic to prevent invoices with the same ID from existing on a single `Customer`

Here are some of the advantages:

1. You can query for `Customer`
2. Querying an `Invoice` by `invoice_id` will return the `Customer` instance, along with all invoices. (This could be a pro and a con, actually - you need logic to return the invoice from the customer)

Here is a more common solution, but by no means is it necessarily the "right solution."
This solution uses ancestor relationships, that allow you to keep writes to `Invoice` and
the related `Customer` atomic - so you could maintain aggregate invoice statistics on the
`Customer` level. (`total_orders`, `total_gross`, etc.)

```
class Invoice(ndb.Model):
    customer = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.key.parent(), indexed=False)  # when not indexed, this is essentially a @property

class Customer(ndb.Model):
    def get_invoice_by_id(self, invoice_id):
        """Returns a customer Invoice by invoice_id. Raises KeyError if invoice is not present."""
        invoice_key = ndb.Key(Invoice._get_kind(), invoice_id, parent=self.key)
        return invoice_key.get()

    def query_invoices(self):
        """Returns ndb.Query for invoices by this Customer."""
        return self.query(ancestor=self.key)

invoice = Invoice(parent=customer.key, **invoice_properties)
```

Good luck with Appengine! Once you get the hang of all of this, it is a truly rewarding platform.

**Update:**

Here is some additional code for transactionally updating customer aggregate totals as I mentioned above.

```
def create_invoice(customer_key, gross_amount_paid):
    """Creates an invoice for a given customer.

    Args:
        customer_key: (ndb.Key) Customer key
        gross_amount_paid: (int) Gross amount paid by customer
    """

    @ndb.transactional
    def _txn():
        customer = customer_key.get()
        invoice = Invoice(parent=customer.key, gross_amount=gross_amount_paid)

        # Keep an atomic, transactional count of customer aggregates
        customer.total_gross += gross_amount_paid
        customer.total_orders += 1

        # batched put for API optimization
        ndb.put_multi([customer, invoice])  

        return invoice

    return _txn()
```

The above code works in a `single entity group transaction` (e.g. `ndb.transactional(xg=False)`) because `Invoice` is a child entity to `Customer`. If that connection is lost, you would need `xg=True`. (I'm not sure if it's more expensive, but it is less optimized)

Comment: Thank you @Josh, I really appreciate your effort. I am gonna try implement your suggested structure in my little invoicing app now. Thank you again !

Comment: No sweat - I've added some code that should help you understand the importance of the ancestor relationship and the value-add that planning entity schemas ahead of time can bring.