# appengine datastore model for twitter like showing posts from users followed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datastore, nosql

I am working on a web system where a feature is similar to Twitter's concept of following a list of users and seeing their posts as a list.

The simple model I came up with requires `join` operation which is not available in `datastore`.

```
class Post(Model):
   author = reference to user id
   content = text content

class Following(Model):
   author = reference to user id
   followed_by = reference to user id
```

The frequent operation is to display a list of posts (sorted in time) from users followed by the current user.

With the above model, it can only be done in two steps:

```
authors = Following.author when Following.followed_by == current_user
posts = Posts with Posts.author in authors
```

Is there any way to achieve this more efficiently?

Comment: That's it.  It takes 2 queries.  Make the first a "keys-only" query to save costs.

Comment: OK. Thanks. If we have to choose between `datastore` and `cloud-SQL`, what should be the thumb rule - something like "if the `authors` query return >200 entities typically, then it makes sense to switch to `SQL`".

Comment: Please note that the `IN` operator is also problematic, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#neq_and_in

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [structure property](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#structured) to store all Posts within the Author object.

There's an [interesting discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072491/app-engine-structured-property-vs-reference-property-for-one-to-many-relationsh) here that might be interesting for you to choose which approach is the best for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single query for displaying posts if you change the algorithm a bit. You could track what posts would need to be displayed for a particular user, with entities like these:

```
class DisplayPost(Model):
   #parent entity = user for which the post should be displayed
   #key ID matches the Post's key ID
   posted = datetime  # if you want timed ordering in display
   expiry = datetime  # optional for periodic cleanup jobs
```

Whenever an author creates a new post you'd just launch task(s) to create such entities for every follower of the author.

Whenever you need to display posts for a user you'd make a single ancestor `keys_only` query to get the list of `DisplayPost` keys:

```
keys = DisplayPost.query(ancestor=user_key, ...).fetch(keys_only=True)
```

From this you obtain a corresponding list of `Post` keys and get the post with a `get_multi()` op, something along these lines:

```
post_keys = [ndb.Key(Post, key.id()) for key in keys]
posts = ndb.get_multi(post_keys)
```

This allows you a much faster response time when displaying posts, with no `join` and no [`IN` (also problematic)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#neq_and_in) ops. Better scalability. The price to pay is always preparing the `DisplayPost`, even if some of them will never be used (if the respective users don't even log in, for example).